# How to insert form data into table as foreign key?

Tags: php, mysql, forms, datalist

I am working on an employee database which will store useraccount information. I have created the forms and am now working on getting the data from the forms into the database. My `Users` table has fields for first name, last name, email, etc. as well as foreign keys organization_id, supervisor_id, etc. So far I have the following code for inserting into the non-foreign-key fields:

```
$f_name = $_POST['firstName'];
$l_name = $_POST['lastName'];
$user_type = $_POST['userType'];
//etc...

$insert = "INSERT INTO Users(f_name, l_name, user_type, email, empl_status_id, reliab_status_id, secr_status_id, ";
$values = "VALUES($f_name, $l_name, $user_type, $email, $empl_status, $reliab_status, $secr_status, ";
if($w_username) {$insert .= "w_username, "; $values .= "'$w_username', ";});

$sql = $insert . $values;
```

All of those fields are required, except for `w_username` which may be left blank. Organization and Supervisor may also be left blank.

The problem is, when they are NOT null, I am not sure how to insert them into the database. In the form, the user may enter their organization in a text field which is linked to a datalist. The datalist should be populated by Organizations that have been previously entered. If a new Organization is entered, it should be added to the database, and consequently, the datalist.

So do I insert the OrganizationID if it's selected from the datalist? How do I do that? I thought maybe I would have to iterate through the list, but then if the list becomes very long eventually, wouldn't that be a problem?

Note: Please explain like I'm 5, I'm really new to this!

Comment: Read about [`PDO`](http://ch2.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and use [prepared statements](http://ch2.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Something like below

```
<?php
          //take OrganizationID as text from form (leave auto complete as it) 

          $sql = "select OrganizationID from org where Organization_name LIKE '".$_POST['OrganizationName']."'";

              //execute it .....
     if(mysql_num_rows()>0){

               $id = $row['id']; //and put in foreign table
      }
    else{
            // insert to org here and get last inserted id calling mysql_insert_id() ;
             // and put in foreign table
    }



 ?>
```